# How to be upgrade-safe with gradle after 12/2018?

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If you upgrade Gradle to Version >= 3, you got a notice, that compile is deprecated and will be removed on 12/2018 if you run `react-native run-android`

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of
>   2018.

So the question here is, how do I keep my App upgrade-safe if you use third-party components, and if they don't replace `compile` by `implements`?

Will we have to fork each Component to solve this?